# How can I configure a "send email" workflow at Umbraco?

Tags: workflow, umbraco

I am using Umbraco Forms v.10 and I'm trying to set up a workflow of sending email (without template) when the form is submitted.
The form works, I can see the entries at Umbraco's backoffice but I did not get any email.

At Logs I get the following error at Logs:

"There was a problem sending an email to {Email} from Workflow for Form {FormName} with id {FormId} for Record with unique id {RecordId}","@l":"Error","@x":"MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpProtocolException: The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected."

The SMTP is the following:

[SMPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnFpi.png)

Did I miss something?
I cannot actually find any documentation about that at Umbraco.

Comment: Are you sure your SMTP settings are correct? If you're running your site on your local computer, it's very unlikely you have an SMTP server on "localhost". If your Umbraco site is on a shared host, it's also unlikely the SMTP server is "localhost". So I think your SMTP settings are incorrect and that's why Umbraco is unable to send the email for you.

Comment: Thank you Mikkel for your answer. 
Yes, it is running on localhost, how should SMTP be set in that case?

Comment: It has to be set according to your webhosts instructions. If your webhost provider is "Simply.com", try search for "Simply.com SMTP" and find their SMTP settings. It could eg. be "host: smtp.simply.com", "port: 25" etc. :)

Comment: Thank you. I will check somethings and try that.

Comment: Alright, great. I'll post an answer, so please mark it as the answer, if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your SMTP settings are most likely incorrect. If you're running your site on your local computer, it's very unlikely you have an SMTP server on "localhost". If your Umbraco site is on a shared host, it's also unlikely the SMTP server is "localhost". So I think your SMTP settings are incorrect and that's why Umbraco is unable to send the email for you.

Find out your webhosts SMTP details, if your webhost was Simply.com, the credentials would be something along the lines of:

Host: smtp.simply.com

Port: 25